Using Bamboo, how to store a global settings.xml for maven build
Attempting to build our team's first CI/CD pipeline with Bitbucket and Bamboo.  The problem I have is the default settings.xml for Maven 3.9.2 is not using the Mvn Repository I need it to.  I have since created a second repo and the only file in that repo is the settings.xml that I want to use.
The Bamboo agent is on a corporate box and not my local machine.
Repo1 - code to actually build
Repo2 - ONLY settings.xml
Following the advice here --> Atlassian Article
Currently the Build Plan is:
Source Code Checkout (for the actual code)
Source Code Checkout (settings.xml) & specify checkout directory as mvnSettings
Maven 3.X with Goals as "-s mvnSettings/settings.xml clean install"
It is not picking up the settings.xml as intended.  Would love any help from a Bamboo Expert so I can be a hero at work on Monday!
Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer:  I used a Bamboo key/value in the maven goals as thus and it now works:
-s ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/mvnSettings/settings.xml
